# Are you "Dinky Die"? And what does Dinky Die mean?

Tags: slang, australian-english

Australia day is nearly upon us! And that means it's time to throw another chop on the barbie and say *real* Aussie things like "dinky die".

Stone the crows, what's that even mean, "dinky die"? I've been saying it for years in sentences like

> I'm true blue, fair dinkum, ridgy didge, *dinky die* Aussie.

Does anyone know where "dinky die" came from and the correct usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dinky-die) says it's an adjective meaning:

> 1. (Australian slang) Genuine, true.
> 2. (Australian slang, by extension) Authentically
>      Australian.
> 3. (Australian slang) Honest, on the level.
> 4. (Australian slang) True blue, steadfastly loyal.

And etymology:

> Fanciful diminutive form of dinkum.

It's use goes back at least as far as this [16 November 1917](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/40267992?searchTerm=%22dinky%20die%22&searchLimits=l-textSearchScope=%2aignore%2a%7C%2aignore%2a|||exactPhrase=dinky+die|||l-word=%2aignore%2a%7C%2aignore%2a|||fromyyyy|||notWords|||anyWords|||tomm|||toyyyy=1980|||todd|||frommm|||fromdd|||sortby=dateAsc) song in the *Cairns Post* (Qld. : 1909 - 1954), where it's used six times:

> THE DINK Y-DI SOLDIER. [The Sole Property of Ernest Lauri.]
>
> ...
>
> Warm blankets at night, an enj-yable day,
>   A nobleman's life, an' a gentleman's pay,—
>   Be a sport, an' a dinky-di soldier!"